# Replace <br> with an horizontal line which adapts its width to the container: possible?

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'd like to achieve something like this:

html:

```
<wathever>Hello this is<br topMargin="2px" botMargin="1px"/>my example</wathever>
```

result:

```
Hello this is
_____________ 
my example
```

The line should adapt its length according to the container's width and I should be free to decide the upper and lower margin.
Is this possible **by css alone?**

I am including extJS tag (this is an explaination for extjs experts, if you don't know what extjs is just ignore this part) as well because I'd like to use this feature for the headers of a grid, so to obtain a multiline header. I already tried using GroupHeader with something like this:

```
 columns:[{
        text: 'Hello this is',
        columns: [{
            text     : 'my example',
        },..
```

but I am not satisfied with final result, mainly for 2 reasons:

1)Even though I am using a groupheader feature the subheader will be just one all the time, so in the end I am using a more complex component to achieve something very simple.

2)The header's menu appears both in the top and bottom header, while I'd like just one header menu.

As the header's text can be an html I'd like to just adapt the 
 tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably replace the `<br>` with an `<hr>` and style it how you want. Alternatively, just wrap "Hello this is" and "my example" in their own elements (like a `<p>` for example) and style one of those with a top or bottom border.

```
.main-part {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

<div class="my-header">
    <p class="main-part">Hello this is</p>
    <p>my example</p>
</div>
```